# Batch have a similar to BASH for *

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have never used Batch. Is there a way to have a long link:

`C:/hello/worlds/today/is/a/good/day.git`

and change it to this:

`day.git`

I try this but Batch does not use

```
:zero
SET TEMP=%GIT:~%n%,%n%%
if %TEMP%==/* (goto :first) else (goto :zero) :: BASH idea

:first
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Expected Output?

Comment: I don't see how this has anything with Bash to do. `for f in *; do` in Bash would simply translate to a similar `for` loop in CMD. The standard Bash parameter substitution would be `${f##*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a standard `for` loop, and use the modifiers for filename and extension. This works because the backward and/or forward slash is treated as a path separator with the modifier.

Example:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "link=C:/hello/worlds/today/is/a/good/day.git"
For %%G In ("%link%") Do Echo %%~nxG

Pause
```

Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to see its usage information, and the available modifiers, to learn more.